# Which pixels did that drawmesh operation just draw to?

Tags: mesh, direct3d9

Ok, it's a relatively simple problem, I want to know where, in screen space, a particular mesh was just drawn. I plan on then storing that information in a data store of some kind so that when I interact with something in screen space, I can lookup in the register and find the object, i.e, click on the spaceship drawn on the screen and then select target etc.

I can't find any way of finding out which pixels the mesh was drawn to though...

Alternatively, if I'm missing something obvious regarding what it is that I Want to do, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that. But you can use another texture as render target and render those meshes with unique colors.

So for example you give #FF0000 to your mesh A and draw it also to your second render target with that color. Now when you select a pixel from 2nd render target and look at that color, if it is #FF0000 you can understand that, the pixel is a part of mesh A. Thus you can easily pick the mesh drawn on a certain pixel when you click one of those pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you Unproject your screen space coords into 3D space? The only complication I had was the fact that I'd be left with a plane, I could check if a Mesh intersected with that plane but I often had multiple candidates for 'picking'.

Check out Google for DirectX Unproject and there are various articles discussing it. It's sometimes complicated for some to implement but done well it's actually pretty nifty; don't get put off by the people online who say it doesn't work, it does work!